# getopt usage with/without option

Tags: c, arguments, command-line-arguments, getopt, argp

I'm writing a simple code making use of `*argv[]` parameter. I'd like to know whether I can use `getopt()` function for the following intent.

```
./myprogram -a PATH
./myprogram PATH
```

The program can either take merely `PATH` (e.g. `/usr/tmp`) or take `-a` option in addition to `PATH`. Can `getopt()` be used for this state? If can, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The program can either take merely `PATH` (e.g. `/usr/tmp`) or take option in addition to `PATH`. Can `getopt()` be used for this state? If can, how?

Certainly.  I'm not sure where you even see a potential issue, unless its that you don't appreciate POSIX's and `getopt()`'s distinction between *options* and *arguments*.  They are related, but not at all the same thing.

`getopt()` is fine with the case that no options are in fact specified, and it gives you access to the non-option arguments, such as `PATH` appears to be for you, regardless of how many options are specified.  The usual usage model is to call `getopt()` in a loop until it returns `-1` to indicate that no more options are available from the command line.  At each step, the global variable `optind` variable provides the index of the next `argv` element to process, and after `getopt()` (first) returns -1, `optind` provides the index of the first non-option argument.  In your case, that would be where you expect to find `PATH`.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const char options[] = "a";
    _Bool have_a = 0;
    char *the_path;
    int opt;

    do {
        switch(opt = getopt(argc, argv, options)) {
            case -1:
                the_path = argv[optind];
                // NOTE: the_path will now be null if no path was specified,
                //       and you can recognize the presence of additional,
                //       unexpected arguments by comparing optind to argc
                break;
            case 'a':
                have_a = 1;
                break;
            case '?':
                // handle invalid option ...
                break;
            default:
                // should not happen ...
                assert(0);
                break;
        }
    } while (opt >= 0);
}
```

Comment: Sir what do you mean by saying `Certainly. I'm not sure where you even see a potential issue, unless its that you don't appreciate POSIX's and getopt()'s distinction between options and arguments. They are related, but not at all the same thing.` ? I don't know whether there is/are difference(s) between POSIX's and getopt()'s options and args. Shouldn't I use getopt() for such a case?

Comment: @snr, you can totally use `getopt()` for your case, as indeed my example code demonstrates.  I was simply venturing a wild guess about why you're uncertain about that being so, and it sounds like I may have been right.  Options, arguments to options, and non-option arguments are all conveyed to your program *via* its arguments, but options are not themselves arguments, nor do they necessarily map to arguments in 1:1 fashion.  Options correspond to and are represented by individual option letters, not whole arguments, and `getopt()` can distinguish these from non-option arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Using an optstring of `"a"` allows an argument of `-a` to act as a flag.
`optind` helps detect that only one additional argument is present.
The program can be executed as `./program -a path` or `./program path`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char op = ' ';//default value
    int opt;

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "a")) != -1)//optstring allows for -a argument
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'a':
            op = 'a';//found option, set op
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: unknown option %c\n", argv[0], optopt);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if ( optind + 1 != argc)//one argument allowed besides optstring values
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-a] PATH\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("%s %c\n", argv[optind], op);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that recognizing options that are presented after a non-option argument is an extension.  POSIX-conforming `getopt()` does not do that. GNU `getopt()`, which behaves as you describe by default, might *also* not do that, depending on the option string and on the process's environment.